# Django post in nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models :Workflow,WorkflowLevels,WorkflowLevelPermissions:

models.py :

```
class Workflow(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None,
                                   null=True)
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               default=None, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'tenant')


class WorkflowLevel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          editable=False)
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='levels', default=None,
                                 null=False)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=False)
    operation = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None,
                                 null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('workflow', 'level')


class WorkflowPermission(models.Model):
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True,
                                  default=None, null=False)


class WorkflowLevelPermission(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          editable=False)
    level = models.ForeignKey(WorkflowLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              default=None, null=False,
                              related_name='workflow_permissions')
    permission = models.ForeignKey(WorkflowPermission,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   default=None, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('level', 'permission')

    def short_name(self):
        return self.permission.short_name
```

Im using nested seriarlizers to display Workflow data in this format

.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "test",
    "description": "Easy",
    "levels": [
        {
            "level": 1,
            "operation": "AND",
            "workflow_permissions": [
                {
                    "short_name": "admin_approval"
                },
                {
                    "short_name": "coordinator_approval"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "operation": "AND",
            "workflow_permissions": []
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

The serializers:

```
class WorkflowPermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = WorkflowPermission
        fields = '__all__'


class WorkflowLevelPermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    short_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('short_name')

    class Meta:
        model = WorkflowLevelPermission
        fields = ['short_name']

    def short_name(self):
        return self.permission.short_name


class WorkflowLevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    workflow_permissions = WorkflowLevelPermissionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkflowLevel
        fields = ['level', 'operation', 'workflow_permissions']


class WorkflowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    levels = WorkflowLevelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
         model = Workflow
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'levels')
```

I want to be able to POST data in the same format in the Workflow API view.RIght now it shows error:
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `exzaacademy.els.tenantmgmt.serializers.WorkflowSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
How do i write the correct create()  method?

Im overriding create method as:

```
class WorkflowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  levels = WorkflowLevelSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Workflow
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'levels', 'tenant')

    def create(self, validated_data):
    levels = validated_data.pop('levels')
    workflow = Workflow.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for level in levels:
        permissions = level.pop('workflow_permissions')
        level=WorkflowLevel.objects.create(
            workflow=workflow,
            level=level['level'],
            operation=level['operation']
        )

        for permission in permissions:
            WorkflowLevelPermission.objects.create(
                level=level,
                permission=permission
            )

    return workflow
```

Im getting errors : WorkFLowLevelPermission.level must be a level instance

Comment: https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested could be of use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
class WorkflowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 levels = WorkflowLevelSerializer(many=True)

 class Meta:
    model = Workflow
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'levels')

 def create(self, validated_data):
    levels = validated_data.pop('levels')
    workflow=Workflow.objects
   .create(**validated_data,tenant=self.context['request'].user.tenant)

    for index,level in enumerate(levels):
        permissions = level.pop('workflow_permissions')
        level_var = WorkflowLevel.objects.create(
            workflow=workflow,
            level=level['level'],
            operation=level['operation']
        )
        print("Initial data",self.initial_data)
        for permission in self.initial_data['levels'][index]['workflow_permissions']:
            permission_obj = WorkflowPermission.objects
           .filter(short_name=permission['short_name']).first()
            WorkflowLevelPermission.objects.create(
                id=uuid.uuid4().hex,
                level=level_var,
                permission=permission_obj
            )

    return workflow
```

Answer (score 2):

what you need to do is override `create` function in the serializer `WorkflowSerializer` as mentioned here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers . keep in mind that for `POST` `create` and for `PUT` or `PATCH` override `update`. here you have to do the logic for creating/updating your model manually. you can always access the received data from `validated_data` and raw data from `self.initial_data`. please follow the above guide for writable nested serializer.

Here I am seeing that you have another nested serializer inside a nested serializer. so this is going to be complex put possible to implement.

In such a case, the following guide might be very useful: https://medium.com/profil-software-blog/10-things-you-need-to-know-to-effectively-use-django-rest-framework-7db7728910e0

see section **9. Handling multiple creates/updates/deletes in nested serializers**

Comment: In this case can i copy the mixin directly and replace update with create? (As shown in the second link)

Comment: can you please rechech the question?I have updated the create method i wrote!

Comment: you have multiple `levels` and in each `level` have multiple `workflow_permissions` so in the first for loop `for level in levels:`, treat each level as nested object and `pop` out the `workflow_permissions` and then save the level, after that **for each** `workflow_permission` create workflow permission with created level.
basically **Treat each level as nested object and do similler as you did in first for loop**

Comment: for specific question in update edit, change to `level = WorkflowLevel.objects.create(
            workflow=workflow,
            level=level['level'],
            operation=level['operation']
        )`

Comment: can you please post as answer here?

Comment: this still shows error.Check my create method again!

Comment: Now it is showing same error for permissions.Cannot assign "OrderedDict()": "WorkflowLevelPermission.permission" must be a "WorkflowPermission" instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
class WorkflowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  levels = WorkflowLevelSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Workflow
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'levels', 'tenant')

    def create(self, validated_data):
    levels = validated_data.pop('levels')
    workflow = Workflow.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for level in levels:
        permissions = level.pop('workflow_permissions')
        level_var = WorkflowLevel.objects.create( # Change Here
            workflow=workflow,
            level=level['level'],
            operation=level['operation']
        )

        for permission in permissions:
            WorkflowLevelPermission.objects.create(
                level=level_var, # Change Here
                permission=permission
            )

    return workflow
```

Comment: Cannot assign "OrderedDict()": "WorkflowLevelPermission.permission" must be a "WorkflowPermission" instance...The same error is now showing for permission arg

Comment: I think its because actually permissions are stored in another model workflowpermissions]

Comment: then create `permission = Permission.objects.create(short_name=[put value here])` and then create `WorkflowLevelPermission`

Comment: Not that way ..See my WorkflowLevelPermissionSerializer im getting a short_name which gives self.permission.short_name ..This "permission" is a workflowPermission instance

Comment: `SerializerMethodField` is a read only field so it validated data dosent give its value,Either change the `SerializerMethodField` or access that value form `self.initial_data`

Comment: if i change serializermethod field ,How can i access the WorkflowPermissions model?

Comment: by another serializer, just like you are accessing data of `level`

Comment: did you tried to access `self.initital_data`, that also can be useful.

Comment: did you mean :  def short_name(self):
        return self.initial_data['permission']

Comment: add this line after `def create(self, validated_data):` `print(self.initial_data)`
this gives us raw unvalidated data received by the serializer.

Comment: ok..after getting this shoulld i simply parse the json and store into the models? to create the WorkFLowLevelPermissions?

Comment: yes, if its work for you, go ahed. also note that will not be json format bu dict format